# Stop ALL instances of audio, even hidden ones

Tags: html, dom, audio, time

How do I stop (and reset current time to 0) of ALL instances of audio on the entire DOM, even hidden ones? I'm unable to stop the currently playing audio with this code.

```
$('.link').on('click', function(e){
    $('.pagecontainer>div').fadeOut();
    $(this.getAttribute("href")).fadeIn();  
    stopAudio();
});

function stopAudio() { //fade out and stop any current audio
    $('audio').animate({volume: 0}, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.each($('audio'), function () {
            this.currentTime=0;
            this.pause();
        });
    },1000)
}

$('.sound').on('play', function () { //since volume was faded out, reset volume when click play button
    $('audio').animate({volume: 1}, 100);
});

....
....

<a href="#page1" class="link">Audio 1</a>
<a href="#page2" class="link">Audio 2</a>
<a href="#page3" class="link">Audio 3</a>

<div class="pagecontainer">

    <div id="page1"> //all three audio elements are in exact same spot
                     //clicking page link fades in current audio and fades in new one
        <audio controls loop class="sound">
            <source src="../../site/music/music1.mp3"/>
            <source src="../../site/music/music1.ogg"/>
        </audio>
    </div>

    <div id="page2">
        <audio controls loop class="sound">
            <source src="../../site/music/music2.mp3"/>
            <source src="../../site/music/music2.ogg"/>
        </audio>
    </div>

    <div id="page3">
        <audio controls loop class="sound">
            <source src="../../site/music/music3.mp3"/>
            <source src="../../site/music/music3.ogg"/>
        </audio>
    </div>

</div>
```

When I click a link to another page, I need to stop and reset all three audio elements. Currently since it doesn't stop, the moment I click the play button of the audio element that fades in, I hear two audios playing at the same time. Though interestingly the audio does fade out.

Note that all three audio elements are in the exact same spot, which is intended.

Comment: I am presuming this is a typo but you have two `div id="page1"` elements on the page. Could this be an issue possibly?

Comment: Oh yeah it's a typo. It's not actually my code, I'm just writing up a quick example. This is the structure of my code though. Edited.

Comment: Strange I don't get that behaviour using your code in Chrome. It works as you mention it should.